# F# recursive function exit?

Tags: f#

I am very new to F# programming.  I am looking for an answer as to why the following recursive function will exit when the n=0 condition is reached.  Does the "then 1" syntax have a special meaning that equates to EXIT?

```
let rec factorial n = 
    if n = 0 
    then 1 
    else n * factorial (n - 1)
```

Comment: `if` is an expression, and the last expression in a function acts as the return value.

Answer (score 6):

Functional programming languages are **expression oriented**, as opposed to statement oriented. This means that everything is an expression that can be evaluated into a value.

The control flow structures, `if` and `match`, are also just expressions. The compiler checks that all branches of these expressions return the same type.

If you're familiar with the conditional ternary operator in other languages, F#'s expression `if true then 1 else 0`, is equivalent to `true ? 1 : 0`.

Furthermore, the function doesn't "exit" as such. It completes evaluation. Each instance of the function (there will be `n + 1` instances) completes evaluation at the end of the `if`/`then`/`else` expression.